# One word for having the right to rule on a case before anyone else

Tags: single-word-requests, legalese

I recall that there is a word used in law to refer to the right of a certain court to take up a case before a subordinate court can.

For example, if only the Supreme Court has the right to rule on a case related to terrorism (and not any other court), we say that the Supreme Court has a ______ on cases related to terrorism.

Comment: You may find that the Law site is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @WS2 Apparently we have a "legalese" tag here, but not for questions exactly like this one?

Comment: @Chaim But the question here is about some complex legal principle which one suspects does not arise every day. If they are talking here about the UK, I'm not a lawyer, but I've never heard of a case going direct to the Supreme Court (or its predecessor the Judicial Committee of the House of Lords). The "legalese" tag I suspect is for everyday legal language.

Comment: @WS2 I don't really follow any of that. I don't see any suggestion of the United Kingdom, I don't see why "legalese" should be reserved for everyday legal language as opposed to complex legal principles which do not arise every day, and I don't know how we could have any valuable intuition about whether exclusive jurisdiction is some complex legal principle, or how often a case goes directly to the Supreme Court, or how often one would need to do so for our purposes.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not angry, and I hope I don't sound angry. But when I post stuff to the stack exchange and people tell me that I should have posted somewhere else, it always strikes me as easily said.

Comment: @WS2 What happens if the government of Scotland runs into a disagreement with the government of Wales? Who settles such disputes? I'm not aware of how it is in the UK either, but in India (where I'm from), inter-state disputes are in the **original jurisdiction** of the Supreme Court of India. No other body can take this case up: even the House of States needs the consent of the Supreme Court in this matter.

Comment: @AravindSuresh You are underlining my point, which is that this is fundamentally a legal question - not simply one about the English language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_jurisdiction), the free encyclopedia:

> In civil procedure, ***exclusive jurisdiction*** exists where one court has
>   the power to adjudicate a case to the exclusion of all other courts.
>   It is the opposite situation from ***concurrent jurisdiction*** (or non
>   exclusive jurisdiction), in which more than one court may take
>   jurisdiction over the case.

This is not what you asked, but I think one might easily confuse this concept with another, as this author seems to, also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_jurisdiction), the free encyclopedia:

> In common law legal systems ***original jurisdiction*** of a court is the
>   power to hear a case for the first time, as opposed to ***appellate
>   jurisdiction***, when a higher court has the power to review a lower
>   court's decision. Original jurisdiction refers to the right of the
>   Supreme court to hear a case for the first time. It has the exclusive
>   right to hear all cases that deal with disputes between states, or
>   between states and the union government. It also has original
>   jurisdiction over cases brought to the court by ordinary people
>   regarding issues to the importance of society at large.

It's puzzling that the author of the second-quoted paragraph says that the Supreme court "has the exclusive right" to hear certain cases, as the point is not about the exclusive right to hear the case but rather the right to give the legal question its first hearing as distinct from an appeal.

Comment: I am convinced that the word—or rather, compound—is "original jurisdiction". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think  the  word you are looking for  is *prerogative*.

prerogative  is  a special right of the king or the courts.

See the link

https://www.yourdictionary.com/prerogative